# Closed surfaces and Multivariable Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to know if a surface is closed by its equation(for example, the surface: $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} + z^2 = 1$) only using Multivariable Calculus ? If so, how ? I'd like references(books) that explain this.

Comment: What do you mean by closed?

Comment: By closed, I mean that the surface delimit a region in space.

Comment: closed surface means 2d without border

Comment: If you parametrize a line over your surface, and evaluate it over a conservative vector field, it should come out to zero. If it comes out to anything other than zero, you've proven your line isn't closed.

Comment: Let $E$ be a conservative vector field. Then for every closed surface $S$: $$\oint_S E.dS=0$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoidal_vector_field

Comment: @janmarqz: ...and *compact*! Otherwise, $\Bbb R^2$ has no border, but is not considered closed.